# Expected singleton: res.company() error Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-17

I am creating an API that searches and reverses an entry in the account.move model. I am able to find the correct entry and reverse it using the refund_moves() method. However, whenever I try to confirm the reversed entry using the action_post() method, I get a "Expected singleton: res.company()" error.
I've used the action_post() method before on other models such as sale.order/account.move and it works fine.

Code:

```py
@http.route('/update_invoice', website="false", auth='custom_auth', type='json', methods=['POST'])

#Searching for entry
invoice = request.env['account.move'].sudo().search([('matter_id','=',matterID),('account_id','=',accountID),('move_type','=','out_invoice'),('company_id','=',creditor.id)])
        if invoice:
            #Create Reversal
            move_reversal = request.env['account.move.reversal'].with_context(active_model="account.move", active_ids=invoice.id).sudo().create({
                'date': intakeDate,
                'reason': 'Balance Adjustment',
                'journal_id': invoice.journal_id.id,
            })

            #Reverse Entry
            move_reversal.refund_moves()
            
            #Search for created reversed entry
            refundInvoice = request.env['account.move'].sudo().search([('name','=',"/"),('company_id','=',creditor.id),('move_type','=','out_refund')])

            if refundInvoice:
                _logger.info("Refund Invoice Found")

                #Error occurs
                refundInvoice.action_post()
```

Custom Authorization:

```py
    @classmethod
    def _auth_method_custom_auth(cls):
        access_token = request.httprequest.headers.get('Authorization')
        _logger.info(access_token)
        
        if not access_token:
            _logger.info('Access Token Missing')
            raise BadRequest('Missing Access Token')
        
        if access_token.startswith('Bearer '):
            access_token = access_token[7:]
            _logger.info(access_token)
            
        
        user_id = request.env["res.users.apikeys"]._check_credentials(scope='odoo.restapi', key=access_token)
        if not user_id:
            _logger.info('No user with api key found')
            raise BadRequest('Access token Invalid')

        request.update_env(user=user_id)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5841, in ensure_one
    _id, = self._ids
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 2189, in __call__
    response = request._serve_db()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1765, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1792, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1996, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 235, in _dispatch
    response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 222, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 722, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/home/odoo/src/user/account_ext/controllers/main.py", line 411, in update_invoice
    refundInvoice.action_post()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/sale/models/account_move.py", line 63, in action_post
    res = super(AccountMove, self).action_post()
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/account_accountant/models/account_move.py", line 76, in action_post
    res = super().action_post()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 4072, in action_post
    other_moves._post(soft=False)
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/sale_subscription/models/account_move.py", line 13, in _post
    posted_moves = super()._post(soft=soft)
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/account_asset/models/account_move.py", line 109, in _post
    posted = super()._post(soft)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/sale/models/account_move.py", line 99, in _post
    posted = super()._post(soft)
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/account_reports/models/account_move.py", line 48, in _post
    return super()._post(soft)
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/account_avatax/models/account_move.py", line 15, in _post
    res = super()._post(soft=soft)
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/account_invoice_extract/models/account_invoice.py", line 262, in _post
    posted = super()._post(soft)
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/account_inter_company_rules/models/account_move.py", line 14, in _post
    posted = super()._post(soft)
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/account_external_tax/models/account_move.py", line 53, in _post
    return super()._post(soft=soft)
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/account_accountant/models/account_move.py", line 68, in _post
    posted = super()._post(soft)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 3876, in _post
    draft_reverse_moves.reversed_entry_id._reconcile_reversed_moves(draft_reverse_moves, self._context.get('move_reverse_cancel', False))
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 3694, in _reconcile_reversed_moves
    lines.with_context(move_reverse_cancel=move_reverse_cancel).reconcile()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move_line.py", line 2935, in reconcile
    return self._reconcile_plan([self])
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move_line.py", line 2345, in _reconcile_plan
    self._reconcile_plan_with_sync(plan_list, all_amls)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move_line.py", line 2492, in _reconcile_plan_with_sync
    exchange_diff_values = exchange_lines_to_fix._prepare_exchange_difference_move_vals(
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move_line.py", line 2603, in _prepare_exchange_difference_move_vals
    accounting_exchange_date = journal.with_context(move_date=exchange_date).accounting_date
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1207, in __get__
    self.compute_value(recs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1389, in compute_value
    records._compute_field_value(self)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 424, in _compute_field_value
    return super()._compute_field_value(field)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4867, in _compute_field_value
    fields.determine(field.compute, self)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 102, in determine
    return needle(*args)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_journal.py", line 366, in _compute_accounting_date
    journal.accounting_date = temp_move._get_accounting_date(move_date, has_tax)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 4358, in _get_accounting_date
    lock_dates = self._get_violated_lock_dates(invoice_date, has_tax)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 4389, in _get_violated_lock_dates
    return self.company_id._get_violated_lock_dates(invoice_date, has_tax)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/company.py", line 369, in _get_violated_lock_dates
    self.ensure_one()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5844, in ensure_one
    raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: res.company()
```

Update:
I added the company using with_company() to the confirmation method and it fixed the problem

```py
refundInvoice.with_company(invoice.company_id).action_post()
```

Comment: I have a lot of questions: Which Odoo version? Which user is logged in when using the API? Is multi-company feature activated?

Comment: I am using odoo17, multi-companies is activated, and I'm not sure what you mean by user logged in. I'm using a custom authorization that uses the user's custom API key to make sure that its a user in the system. I added the code for the custom authorization as well as the http.route

Comment: Okay i'm blind, didn't see the first code line. Hm, i'm not experienced with how the context or environment is build on those calls, but i guess something is missing in your custom auth, when you set the user for the env. Is the user active in a company? And when yes, in which company? The one he needs for the positing of invoices/refunds?

Comment: Yes I am logging in to the right user and the user has access to all of the companies. I've created other API's that create entries in the sale.order and account.move model and confirm them using the action_post() method. Its only when I reverse it and try to confirm the reverse is where I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Debug below line:

```
File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 4389, in _get_violated_lock_dates
    return self.company_id._get_violated_lock_dates(invoice_date, has_tax)
```

and check what comes in `self.company_id` and `self._context`

- There must be 0 or more than 1 company records in self.company.
- So when it calls _get_violated_lock_dates method, it assumes it have one company_id and proceeds.
- Try checking from where this self.company id is not getting exact 1 value

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Since the company record is missing, I passed the company of the invoice using refundInvoice.with_company(invoice.company_id).action_post() when I confirm the reversed entry.

Comment: Great ! sometimes it can be solvable by adding context like: self.env['account.payment'].sudo().with_context(default_company_id=user_rec.company_id.id).create(payment_order_vals)